# Is there a way to get every frame of a GIF animation in Python?

Tags: python, animation, frame, gif

I'm developing an engine with Python and Pygame, and it already has built-in support for animations with spritesheets. Nevertheless, It would be really interesting to be able to get the frames from a gif so that I could add to the Animation object as an alternative to spritesheets.

Is there a library to access the frames in a gif file, or even video, in Python? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **MoviePy**.

> MoviePy is a Python module for script-based movie editing. It enables basic operations (cuts, concatenations, title insertions) to be done in a few lines, and can be used for advanced compositing and special effects.

http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/

Also, here is a tutorial on how to use it to make gifs, which could prove useful:

http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/making-animated-gifs-from-video-files-with-python/